# Batch json API in .NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I've been working on a project now for  while which is devied between something we call "webs" (bad name, I know) and "buildings". Each web can have 1 or more buildings, and when you log in you log in to a particular web. Traditionally this was set up as separate vhosts in IIS, thus they were actually separate webs, except for the fact that they all ran the same code-base, however the new system that's being written moves away from this pattern.

Also, in the old system; what building you were currently viewing was stored in a session-variable, in other words one couldn't direct link to anything. Say for instance that you log in to web 01 on building 01 and navigate to the ao_list.asp (the old web was classic asp), you'd end up with an url looking something along the lines of `web01.domain.com/ao/ao_list.asp`, however in the new system you would have a url like this: `domain.com/web-01/building-01/ao/`. This ofcause takes you to the `Index`-method of the `AOViewController`.

All this work currently, and there is no problem with the navigation at all. In addition to said URL; there is a API-url that closely match the web-url given by `domain.com/api/web-01/buildin-01/ao/`. This also works great.

But from here comes the problem. Decorating every Controller in the project is the custom `AuthorizeAttribute` I wrote, that takes into consideration what building/web you are browsing while checking the user right. For instance; no user should have access to web's that isn't their respective user-web. And users can have different rights on different buildings.

The attribute works by getting the building and web-number off from the route-dictionary, then using that when calculating the user-rights, and this works as one would suspect. However, there has been proven a need for API-methods that can aggregate API-calls over several buildings, and I'm struggling trying to figure out how I can implement these.

For instance; whenever a user goes to the start-page of the application; a ajax-requests is made to get a list over outstanding AO's in every building the user has access to. This is currently made one request per building, which might result in hundreds of requests in the worst case scenario. This of-cause is unacceptable, so what I would like would be to be able to do something like calling `GET /api/web-01/ao/?buildings=01,02,03,04,06` then loop over the buildings on the server-side and return something like this:

```
[
    {"building":"01","data":<result of calling /api/web-01/building-01/ao>},
    {"building":"02","data":<result of calling /api/web-01/building-02/ao>},
    {"building":"03","data":<result of calling /api/web-01/building-03/ao>},
    etc...
]
```

And of cause, I would like to simply get an error if any permissions were attempted violated along the way.

Is there a good way I can implement this without having to change the actual implementation of the `Index`-method on the `API.AOController`?

Currently I implement buildings by adding a simple look-up in the route-dictionary during `OnActionExecuting` in a base Controller that all my controllers extend, so what I was thinking was that I could check for the existence of a buildings-querystring-parameter and if it was present create several instances of the current controller, set the building-variable on the "child" controller and call the method in question, but I don't know if this is a good way to do it, and I don't know how to invoke the AutorizeAttribute on the "child" either, so what I'm asking (after writing all this) is a good way to orchestrate this problem in a good way :).

**[Edit]**

### TLDR;

I have a mvc3 page setup with urls like:
`domain.com/api/web-01/buildin-01/ao/`
`domain.com/api/web-01/buildin-02/ao/`
etc.
These are all API calls that returns JSON-data after running a custom Autorize-attribute.
What I would like is to be able to do something like `domain.com/api/web-01/ao/?buildings=01,02` which would result in getting the accumulated response of the two calls above (grouped by their respective building ofcause) while still running the Autorize-attribute **for each** building. And if that Autorize-attribute would fail for one of the buildings it the whole request should fail. And also; I would like to be able to do this without having to change the implementation of the `Index`-method of the AOController, but instead having it called multiple times. I think sort of what I want to achieve is to have a single request "act" as if it was actually several requests, without ofcause creating several requestcontexts (which would spawn database-connections etc.). Is this possible?

Comment: if you talked less and coded more it might help. I don't even want to bother reading all that stuff. we don't need to know your life story...can you please simplify this? thanks!

Comment: @Timmerz I tried to make a short version of the problem; though I do think I lose out on some of the info that might be required in order to get the problem as a whole.

Comment: damn. I just read some of that...the problem is that you are way over-complicating this issue. trying to mix and match and boxing yourself in by not wanting to change implementations, etc. which is why you are off writing an essay about this. before you do anything else you need to think about the KISS principle. simplify! I am being blunt, but it's damn good advice.

Comment: Do you have any specific simplifications you could recommend, cause I tried to make the simplest solution to the problem at hand. With regards that the current API-problem is a new one that I didn't think of when I first started, so the thought up solution as to how to handle it might be utterly stupid, it's just the best I could come up with.

Comment: well I mean its very difficult because it's like suggesting sweeping architectural changes and I don't know much about your overall design. I can give a little advice offhand though. if you are using sql, then use set based queries and try to do the restrictions in the query. also, it seems like you are trying to get the authorize attribute to interact with the specifics of the controller methods, and I don't think that's a good idea...use authorize for global sanity check, and do another layer of security at the query level.